# Reshape multidimensional nested PHP array to another format

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional nested array:

```
$arr = array(
    'name'      => 'Root Node',
    'children'  => array(
        array(
            'name'      => 'Node A',
            'children'  => array(
                array(
                    'name'      => 'Node A.1',
                    'children'  => array(
                        array(
                            'name'      => 'Node A.1.1',
                            'children'  => ''
                        ),
                    ),
                ),

                array(
                    'name'      => 'Node A.2',
                    'children'  => ''
                ),
            ),
        ),

        array(
            'name'      => 'Node B',
            'children'  => array(
                array(
                    'name'      => 'Node B.1',
                    'children'  => '',
                ),

                array(
                    'name'      => 'Node B.2',
                    'children'  => ''
                ),
            )
        ),

        array(
            'name'      => 'Node C',
            'children'  => ''
        )
    ),
);
```

Currently this array is upto 4 levels but we can't assume its depth level static to 4 as it may have N levels as well. My goal is to convert this array with individual row array per relation like:

```
$arr = array(
    array( 'Root Node', 'Nodel A', 'Node A.1', 'Node A.1.1' ),
    array( 'Root Node', 'Nodel A', 'Node A.2' ),
    array( 'Root Node', 'Nodel B', 'Node B.1' ),
    array( 'Root Node', 'Nodel B', 'Node B.2' ),
    array( 'Root Node', 'Nodel C' ),
);
```

I know a recursive function should do the trick but I can't figure it out as its not that easy I thought in start. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: use foreach to get in all elements. inside foreach put the values on the table

Comment: I have tried foreach and recursive functions to make it working but couldn't figure it out

Answer (score 2):

Use following code snippet. It should resolve your problem.

```
function makeTreeArr($arr){ 
    $mainarr = []; 
    $tmparr = []; 
    function iterateChildren(&$mainarr,&$tmparr,$node){ 
        $tmparr[] = $node['name']; 
        if(is_array($node['children'])){ 
            foreach($node['children'] as $child){ 
                iterateChildren($mainarr,$tmparr,$child) ;     
            } 
        }else{ 
            $mainarr[] = $tmparr; 
        } 
        array_pop($tmparr ); 
    } 
   iterateChildren($mainarr,$tmparr,$arr); 
   return $mainarr; 
} 
$newarr = makeTreeArr($arr);
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot for your efforts.. However, I have shorten the function further down as:

`function iterateChildren( $node, $mainarr, $tmparr ) { 
 $tmparr[] = $node['name'];
 if( is_array( $node['children'] ) ) {
  foreach($node['children'] as $child){ 
   $mainarr = iterateChildren( $child, $mainarr, $tmparr );
  }
 } else { 
     $mainarr[] = $tmparr; 
 }
 
 array_pop( $tmparr ); 
 return $mainarr;
}`

Answer (score 0):

Follow below protocol to fetch the elements as specified by you.

```
$name0=$arr['name'];
$in1=$arr['children'];
foreach($in1 as $key=>$value)
{
echo $name0.", ";
echo $name1=$in1[$key]['name'].", ";
$in2=$arr['children'][$key]['children'];
    foreach($in2 as $k2=>$v2)
    {
        echo $name2=$in2[$k2]['name'].", ";
        $in3=$arr['children'][$key]['children'][$k2]['children'];
        foreach($in3 as $k3=>$v3)
        {
           echo  $name3=$in3[$k3]['name'].", ";
        }
    }
    echo "</br>";
}
```

**Output :-**

> Root Node, Node A, Node A.1, Node A.1.1, Node A.2,
>
> Root Node, Node B, Node B.1, Node B.2,
>
> Root Node, Node C,

Comment: Thanks for giving it an attempt. Looking at the code snippet, it seems limited to three levels only where I need it to accept any number of levels.

Comment: This is 4 level as specified

Comment: Doesn't matter either 3 or 4 levels till its static with the script. We can't repeat foreach till 100 times for 100 depth levels.